# I have this cucumber code and how to write feature file?

Tags: java, cucumber

```
@Given("^I click on \"(.*?)\" button $")

public void doClickButton(String fieldName) throws Throwable {

}
```

This is my cucumber code .I need feature file for this code.

i have written feature file like

> Given I click on "Gmail" button

But it is not working!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Before writing, read a little ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the regex written in the @Given can you try with removing the space before $

```
@Given("^I click on \"(.*?)\" button$")
```

because in the feature file that the step you have defined may not be ending with a space because of which it would not be able to match the pattern in Step definition class

Comment: How are you running your code...can you please provide the directory structure of your code and how you are running it I.e. with or without maven, from command line or some ide

Comment: Do you get the step definition recommendations while executing on console which will confirm atleast the feature file is loaded and the glue code I.e. the step definition is not loaded

Comment: feature file is executing remaining steps are working only these step not working.it is showing glue code not matching

Comment: I have never executed cucumber with junit but would put my hands on it to get back to answer this question...till now I've executed it using cucumber-jar from command line and in a maven project

Comment: If you are following any article can you provide the link to it so that I will try to go through it.

Comment: Rather than writing the step to go with the glue can you write what you are trying to do and generate the glue from your step?